# Rounding number at certain decimal places in ngIf of angular4

Tags: angular, rounding, angular-template

I am simply trying to validate calculation like below:

```
<div *ngIf="((buyForm.value.rate * buyForm.value.Units)|number:'1.8-8')<=0" class="help-block">Minimum order quantity is 0.00050000</div>
```

But seems like I cannot use decimal pipe like this. Math.round may work, but not clear about the implementation. Do you guys have any example?

Comment: works fine without all those unnecessary parentheses

Comment: which one is unnecessary, should it be like this: buyForm.value.rate * buyForm.value.Units|number:'1.8-8'<

Comment: that worked when I tried it.

Comment: The HTML should be as thin as possible. Try to separate the business logic to the script side only.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  {{((a * b) | number:'1.8-8') <=0 }}
```